# Fn-lock with A1243 keyboard under windows?

Tags: keyboard, windows

I am looking for a fn-lock function under Win 8.1/x64 for my apple keyboard. Most likely this has to be supported by the keyboard driver for the apple keyboard.

1. Not all function keys work on my Apple keyboard as intended. F1/F2/F5/F6/F7 appear to try to fulfill their assigned functions. Keyboard is not defective. there are two to try and using the fn key, the codes are created as intended.
2. IMHO this used to work, just creating F1-F12.
3. This should not be a Bios configurable issue, as the standard F1-F12 are created on a normal windows keyaboard.
4. This is not under Bootcamp, so the "configure bootcamp" option is not available.
5. Key mappers do not permit me to remap function keys. Also the location of the fn-lock key for this keyboard is unclear. What is it on Macs?

I am therefore looking for either
a) a way to toggle fn-lock for the Apple keyboard under windows (without the bootcamp menu)
b) an option for a keyboard driver for the apple keyboard under Windows.

Thanks.